# What file types are associated with an application on Windows7?

Tags: file, windows-7

I want to find out which types of files are associated with Microsoft Word on my System. All these file types should be handled in a special way by my application. How do i get a list of all files types that are associated with an application like Ms-Word? I know there is a dialog to set the default programs. But there is no entry for Ms-Word and i need a mapping in the other direction. I am not sure if this is a programming question at all. This is what I need:

Ms-Word:
.docx
.doc
.odt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That takes a slog through the registry that's not guaranteed to be unambiguous.  Startup Regedit.exe to follow along, open the HKCR hive and look at the registry keys whose name starts with `.`  Quickest way to find relevant ones is by using Edit > Find and type "word".

First one you are likely to find is `.doc`.  Note the default value of the key, that's the *ProgId*.  It is "Word.Document.8" on my machine, I have Office 2013 installed.

The ProgIds are registry keys themselves.  Navigate to HKCR\Word.Document.8 to see what it looks like.  Expand the node to see the sub-keys, the one that matters is `CLSID`.  It is "{00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}".  That has been the guid for Word for the past 20 years.  Whether it will be for the next 20 years is anybody's guess.

You can continue to search but the fidelity start to drop off.  The CLSID is a registry key itself, you can find it back in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID.  The LocalServer32 subkey's default value contains the path to the executable.  "C:\PROGRA~2\MIF5BA~1\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" on my machine.  A *short name* in MS-Dos 8.3 format, yours is pretty likely to read differently.

---

So, for now, I'd recommend to go from `HKCR\.ext` => `HKCR\ProgId\CLSID` and compare with the anointed guid.  It is likely to work for a while, not forever.  Hard-coding the extensions isn't terribly wrong either.  Do note the ambiguity you'll discover when you search, filename extensions like .htm, .pdf, .xml can be opened with Word as well but is not the default association.  And some are not documents, like .wll

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i did find another workaround. At my german version of windows i search for "Dateityp" or "file association" and selected "Dateityp immer mit einem bestimmten Programm oeffnen" or "Make a file type always open in a specific program". The dialog shows the file types mapped to programs. Then i just collected the types that are mapped to Ms-Word.